# How to check whether a TikTok user likes a video or follows a user programmatically?

Tags: android, node.js, web-scraping, tiktok

I am trying to clone an app similar to TikFollower, which is an app for users to boost their likes and followers on TikTok. I am stuck on how to check whether a user likes a specific video (the user gets rewarded some points when the user likes a specific video)

I had come across several APIs for TikTok and most of them are written in Python and Node.js. I am curious about how to integrate them into web/mobile app. Should I construct my own 'API' and how to do so?

Comment: Please mention what APIs have you checked so users can answer details

Comment: https://github.com/szdc/tiktok-api but I'm using the ASP.net framework to do the web application, any ideas on integrating them together?